# Why is every steps printed and not the final string without vowels?

Tags: python

I have seen various questions close to what I am trying to achieve, i.e removing vowels from a string.

My code is as follows (I want to avoid function):

```
word_with_whole_alphabet = input("give me a string bro: ")

vowel = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y"]

for i in word_with_whole_alphabet:
  if i in vowel:
     word_with_whole_alphabet = word_with_whole_alphabet.replace(i, "")
  print(word_with_whole_alphabet)
```

However, I do not understand why the output I have provides me with intermediate steps.

The output is as follows for the word "LALALILALOU"

```
LALALILALOU
LLLILLOU
LLLILLOU
LLLILLOU
LLLILLOU
LLLLLOU
LLLLLOU
LLLLLOU
LLLLLOU
LLLLLU
LLLLL
```

Comment: The ```print``` statement is within the ```for``` loop. Move it to the same indention level as the ```for``` loop.

Comment: The `print` statement is inside the `for` loop, so obviously it will print on each iteration of the loop.  Can you explain why you expected to see only one print?

Comment: ok...many thanks. I still struggle to understand where to indent things where. I am sorry @JohnGordon

Comment: @TomasMichel Indentation defines code blocks in Python. It's crucial to understand how that works. When you use e.g. `if`, every following indented line is part of that `if` block. It's the same with a `for` statement or with `while`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're printing `word_with_whole_alphabet` inside the loop.

To avoid that, Try this:

```
word_with_whole_alphabet = input("give me a string bro: ")

vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "y", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y"]

for vowel in vowels:
    word_with_whole_alphabet = word_with_whole_alphabet.replace(vowel, "")

print(word_with_whole_alphabet)
```

Output:

```
give me a string bro: LALALILALOU
LLLLL
```

Comment: Many thanks this works...so all of this because of the indentation...

Answer (score 2):

Easier way to do this:

Snippet:

```
def remove_vowels(word: None) ->str:
    letters = [char for char in word if char.lower()  not in ''aAeEiIoOuUyY''] 
    return ''.join(letters)

word_with_whole_alphabet = input("give me a string bro: ")
print(remove_vowels(word_with_whole_alphabet))
```

Output:

```
give me a string bro: LALALILALOU
LLLLL
```

Comment: Or a one-liner: `return word.translate(str.maketrans("", "", "AEIOUYaeiouy"))`

Comment: @Matthias. I haven't thought about translate. Thank.

Comment: Many thanks. I cannot accept this as I already acccepted an answer, but this seems interesting, although this seems more complicated. I see the [ ] making me think of a list but yet there is the "for" and "in" in it, as well as "join" which all do not really know. Many thanks this is interesting, but certainly "more advenced".